# Solving a Character printing program using data class

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm having problems with a program. It's a program using a data class to print out movie characters. However I don't have a lot of practice with data classes and don't really know how to use them. So I'm wondering if someone could help me solve this problem?

This is the main

```
import Character 


#  Creates a character called Indiana
   Indiana = Character.Character('Indiana', 'Human', 'Earth')
   print(Indiana.to_string())

#  Creates an empty character later filled with Luke Skywalker
   luke = Character.Character()
   luke.set_name('Luke Skywalker')
   luke.set_kind('Human')
   luke.set_planet('Tatooine')
   print(luke.to_string())
```

I haven't really gotten too far with the data class, so far I've only come up with this

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Character:
   name: str
   kind: str
   planet: str

def char(name,kind,planet):
   set_name = name
   set_kind = kind
   set_planet = planet
```

and the output should be like this

```
Output:

Indiana is a(n) Human from Earth

Luke Skywalker is a(n) Human from Tatooine
```

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Dataclasses automatically create constructors, setters, getters, and string conversion methods as appropriate to the options on the `@dataclass` decorator and the class attributes you define in the body of the class.  Delete your `char` function and do:

```
from Character import Character  

#  Creates a character called Indiana
indiana = Character('Indiana', 'Human', 'Earth')
print(indiana)

#  Creates an empty character later filled with Luke Skywalker
luke = Character('', '', '')
luke.name = 'Luke Skywalker'
luke.kind = 'Human'
luke.planet = 'Tatooine'
print(luke)
```

This prints:

```
Character(name='Indiana', kind='Human', planet='Earth')
Character(name='Luke Skywalker', kind='Human', planet='Tatooine')
```

If you want your `Character`'s fields to have default values, set them in the `Character` class like this:

```
@dataclass
class Character:
    name: str = ''
    kind: str = ''
    planet: str = ''
```

and now you can do `luke = Character()` and it will fill in the three `''` empty strings for you automatically.

If you want to change the way that a `Character` is converted to a string, add a `__str__` method, e.g.:

```
@dataclass
class Character:
    name: str = ''
    kind: str = ''
    planet: str = ''

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}, a {self.kind} from {self.planet}"
```

Note that in Python you don't have to explicitly call a method like `to_string` to print an object as a string; the `print` function will automatically convert its arguments to strings with the `str()` function, which in turn will call the `__str__` method of the object to do the conversion.

Comment: Why are you suggesting assigning to the attributes after the fact, instead of passing the values to `Character` initially?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it; it was part of OP's question.

Comment: Okay , but now I'm getting the error "from Character import Character  
ImportError: cannot import name 'Character' from 'Character'". Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Based on your original code I was assuming you had the `Character` class defined in a file called `Character.py`.  If it's in your "main" file above the rest of your code (this is what I would recommend for a small example like this -- keep it simple!) you don't need an `import` at all.

Comment: Well I would like  to do that, but the point of the exercise is to make a data class in a different file and then import it, to the main file.

Comment: In that case you will need to use the name of that file in your `import` statement.  Maybe name it `character.py` (lowercase) and do `from character import Character`?

Comment: Actually tried it again and it just worked. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting an error when you try to instantiate empty character.. You can avoid that by specifying default value .. To print, you can override **str** method see below

from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass

class Character:

```
    name:str=None
    kind:str=None
    planet:str=None

    def set_char(self,name,kind,planet):
            self.name=name
            self.kind=kind
            self.planet=planet

    def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.name} is a(n) {self.kind} from {self.planet}'
```

Indiana=Character('Indiana','Human','Earth')
print(Indiana)
Luke=Character()
Luke.set_char('Luke SkyWalker','Human','Tatooine')
print(Luke)